# Disable RadioButton under a radioGroup from Adapter class in Android & different radioButton got selected when first 2 item from the list is clicked

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to implement a quiz app where Question List are shown in a RecyclerView. I use CountDownTimer for tracking duration of the test. I want to disable clicking on Radio Button After Time is finished.

The problem I face, I can't disable clicking button from Adapter class. When onFinshed() is called, no value is added in result variable. That's great. I want that. But the problem is, it still possible to select from RadioButton whish is very bad for user experience.

Another Problem I facing is, when I checked radiobutton from view item number 1 and 2, the radio button of item number 9 and 10 got selected.

What I tried is given bellow

`QuizTimer.kt`

```
class QuizTimer(
    private val updateCountdownText: (String)->Unit,
    private val timesUp: ()->Unit
) : CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        val minutes = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60
        val seconds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60

        val formattedTimeInString: String = format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)

        updateCountdownText(formattedTimeInString)
    }

    override fun onFinish() {
        timesUp()
    }

    fun startCounting() {
        start()
    }

    fun finishCounting() {
        cancel()
    }
}
```

`Question.kt`

```
data class Question(
    @SerializedName("ques_id") val quesId: Int?,
    @SerializedName("question") val question: String?,
    @SerializedName("option_a") val optionA: String?,
    @SerializedName("option_b") val optionB: String?,
    @SerializedName("option_c") val optionC: String?,
    @SerializedName("option_d") val optionD: String?,
    @SerializedName("correct_answer") val correctAnswer: String?,
    @SerializedName("marks") val marks: Int?,
    var selectedAnswer: String?
)
```

`QuestionViewHolder.kt`

```
class QuestionViewHolder(private val bindingView: ItemQuestionBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bindingView.root) {

    fun bind(question: Question, onCheckedListener: (Question) -> Unit) {
        bindingView.question = question
        bindingView.root.questionHolder.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            when(checkedId) {
                R.id.optionA -> question.selectedAnswer = "A"
                R.id.optionB -> question.selectedAnswer = "B"
                R.id.optionC -> question.selectedAnswer = "C"
                R.id.optionD -> question.selectedAnswer = "D"
            }
            onCheckedListener(question)
        }
    }

    fun getView() = bindingView.root

    fun disableRadioButton() {
        val questionViewHolderRadioGroup: RadioGroup = getView().questionHolder

        for (i in 0 until questionViewHolderRadioGroup.childCount) {
            (questionViewHolderRadioGroup.getChildAt(i) as RadioButton).isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

`QuestionAdapter.kt`

```
class QuestionAdapter(private val onClickListener: (Question) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionViewHolder>() {

    private var questionList: ArrayList<Question>? = ArrayList()
    var isClickable: Boolean = true
    lateinit var questionViewHolder: QuestionViewHolder

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): QuestionViewHolder {
        val view = ItemQuestionBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return QuestionViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return questionList?.size ?: 0
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: QuestionViewHolder, position: Int) {
        this.questionViewHolder = holder
        holder.bind(questionList?.get(position)!!, onClickListener)
        holder.getView().number_text_view.text = "${position+1}."
    }

    fun replaceData(reminderList: ArrayList<Question>) {
        this.questionList = reminderList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun disableRadioButton() {
        questionViewHolder.disableRadioButton()
    }
}
```

`item_question.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="com.caretutors.api.serviceModel.tutorProfileResponse.Question"/>
        <variable name="question" type="com.caretutors.api.serviceModel.tutorProfileResponse.Question" />
    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_12sdp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="1."
                android:textColor="@color/black_85_percent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text="@{question.question}"
                android:textColor="@color/black_85_percent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/number_text_view"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="What is the Capital of Bangladesh ?" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/questionHolder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_textView">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/optionA"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:text="@{question.optionA}"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_50_percent"
                    tools:text="Dhaka" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/optionB"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:text="@{question.optionB}"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_50_percent"
                    tools:text="Mumbai" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/optionC"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:text="@{question.optionC}"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_50_percent"
                    tools:text="Islamabad" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/optionD"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:text="@{question.optionD}"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_50_percent"
                    tools:text="Yangun" />
            </RadioGroup>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</layout>
```

`TestFragment.kt`

```
class TestFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private val viewModel: TutorProfileViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.tutor_navigation_graph)

    private val questionAdapter: QuestionAdapter by lazy {
        QuestionAdapter {
            if (!questionAdapter.isClickable) {
                context?.showToast("You can't select as time is up")
            } else {
                viewModel.answer[it.quesId!!] = if(it.selectedAnswer == it.correctAnswer) 1 else 0
                println(viewModel.answer)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getLayoutResId() = R.layout.fragment_test

    override fun initWidget() {
        question_recycler_view.adapter = questionAdapter

        val quizTimer = QuizTimer(
            updateCountdownText = { time_remaining_text_view.text = it },
            timesUp = {
                questionAdapter.isClickable = false
                questionAdapter.disableRadioButton()

                for (key in viewModel.answer.keys) viewModel.total += viewModel.answer[key]!!

                context?.showToast("You got ${viewModel.total} out of 10")
            }
        )

        quizTimer.startCounting()
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is a common problem of RecyclerView with repeating items in it showing duplicate values at the same time, as you've mentioned:

> when I checked radiobutton from view item number 1 and 2, the radio button of item number 9 and 10 got selected.

You need to use `setItemViewCacheSize()` in your activity before setting your adapter, which is `QuestionAdapter` like the following, I'm giving a demo code since you didn't add your activity code:

```
yourRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(yourDataList.size());
yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(yourQuestionAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks A lot vai.Take my love from my heart. It works for one of problem. But another problem is still in hanging mood. The Timer problem still not solved

Answer (score 0):

Might be not related but i was building quiz app we had the 10 question and each question has 10sec time. So what i did taken viewpager and was refreshing ui after 10 sec and loading the next question. I would suggest you to go with viewpager it will make process smoother.

If you want you can refer this two classes :

// Fragment for viewpager

```
  class OneToManyQuizContentFragmentKT : BaseFragment(), View.OnClickListener {

private val webListener = View.OnTouchListener { v, event ->
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> (v.parent as View).performClick()
        else -> {
        }
    }
    false
}

private var data: OneToManyQuestionModelKT.Questions? = null
private var listener: OneToManyQuizActivityKT? = null
private val webLongClickListener = View.OnLongClickListener { v -> true }

companion object {
    fun newInstance(position: Int, data: OneToManyQuestionModelKT.Questions): OneToManyQuizContentFragmentKT {
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putInt("position", position)
        args.putSerializable("data", data)
        val fragment = OneToManyQuizContentFragmentKT()
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}

override fun getLayoutResId(): Int {
    return R.layout.fragment_one_to_many_quiz_content_fregment
}

override fun initialization() {
    data = arguments?.getSerializable("data") as OneToManyQuestionModelKT.Questions

}

override fun initView(v: View) {
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //TODO REMOVE THIS AT PRODUCTION
    if (data!!.right_answer.isNotEmpty()) {
        txtRightAns.text = "Right answer: ${data!!.right_answer} "
    }
    if (data!!.difficultyLevel.isNotEmpty()) {
        txtDifficultyLevel.text = "Difficulty Level: ${data!!.difficultyLevel} "
    }
    webQuestion.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "Q - " + (getPosition() + 1) + " " + Utility.setHtmlFont(data!!.question), "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
    webOption1.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, Utility.setHtmlFont(data?.optionOne), "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
    webOption2.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, Utility.setHtmlFont(data?.optionTwo), "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
    webOption3.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, Utility.setHtmlFont(data?.optionThree), "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
    webOption4.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, Utility.setHtmlFont(data?.optionFour), "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
    changeColor()

    webViewSettings(webQuestion)
    webViewSettings(webOption1)
    webViewSettings(webOption2)
    webViewSettings(webOption3)
    webViewSettings(webOption4)

    lnrOption1.setOnClickListener(this)
    lnrOption2.setOnClickListener(this)
    lnrOption3.setOnClickListener(this)
    lnrOption4.setOnClickListener(this)

    webOption1.setOnTouchListener(webListener)
    webOption2.setOnTouchListener(webListener)
    webOption3.setOnTouchListener(webListener)
    webOption4.setOnTouchListener(webListener)

    webOption1.setOnLongClickListener(webLongClickListener)
    webOption2.setOnLongClickListener(webLongClickListener)
    webOption3.setOnLongClickListener(webLongClickListener)
    webOption4.setOnLongClickListener(webLongClickListener)


}

private fun webViewSettings(web: WebView) {
    web.settings?.javaScriptEnabled = true
    web.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
    web.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false
    web.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
    web.settings?.textZoom = 90
}

override fun setupData() {
}

override fun onClick(v: View) {
    when {
        v == lnrOption1 -> selectOption(1)
        v === lnrOption2 -> selectOption(2)
        v === lnrOption3 -> selectOption(3)
        v === lnrOption4 -> selectOption(4)
    }
}


private fun selectOption(ans: Int) {
    if (!Utility.isNetworkAvailable(activity)) {
        showToast(R.string.no_internet_connection)
        return
    }
    data!!.selected_ans = ans
    val ansText = changeColor()
    listener?.onAnswerSelected(data!!.selected_ans, ansText)

}

@FunctionalInterface
interface OnAnswerSelected {
    fun onAnswerSelected(ans: Int, ansText: String)
}

override fun setListeners() {
}

fun setListener(listener: OneToManyQuizActivityKT): OneToManyQuizContentFragmentKT {
    this.listener = listener
    return this
}

private fun getPosition(): Int {
    return arguments!!.getInt("position")
}

private fun changeColor(): String {
    var ansText = ""
    lnrOption1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_gray_test)
    lnrOption2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_gray_test)
    lnrOption3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_gray_test)
    lnrOption4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_gray_test)
    txtOptionA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans_gray_circle)
    txtOptionB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans_gray_circle)
    txtOptionC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans_gray_circle)
    txtOptionD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans_gray_circle)
    txtOptionA.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.black))
    txtOptionB.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.black))
    txtOptionC.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.black))
    txtOptionD.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.black))

    if (data != null && data?.selected_ans != 0) {
        when (data!!.selected_ans) {
            1 -> {
                if (data!!.right_answer == Const.SELECTED_ANS_A) {
                    lnrOption1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_round_option_shape)
                    txtOptionA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_green_circle)
                    txtOptionA.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                } else {
                    lnrOption1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_round_option_shape)
                    txtOptionA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_red_circle)
                    txtOptionA.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                    showRightAnswer(500)

                }
                ansText = data!!.optionOne
                enableDisableView(lnrOption2 as View, false)
                enableDisableView(lnrOption3 as View, false)
                enableDisableView(lnrOption4 as View, false)
            }
            2 -> {

                if (data!!.right_answer == Const.SELECTED_ANS_B) {
                    lnrOption2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_round_option_shape)
                    txtOptionB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_green_circle)
                    txtOptionB.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                } else {
                    lnrOption2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_round_option_shape)
                    txtOptionB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_red_circle)
                    txtOptionB.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                    showRightAnswer(500)
                }
                ansText = data!!.optionTwo
                enableDisableView(lnrOption1 as View, false)
                enableDisableView(lnrOption3 as View, false)
                enableDisableView(lnrOption4 as View, false)
            }
            3 -> {

                if (data!!.right_answer == Const.SELECTED_ANS_C) {
                    lnrOption3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_round_option_shape)
                    txtOptionC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_green_circle)
                    txtOptionC.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                } else {
                    lnrOption3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_round_option_shape)
                    txtOptionC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_red_circle)
                    txtOptionC.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                    showRightAnswer(500)
                }
                ansText = data!!.optionThree
                enableDisableView(lnrOption2 as View, false)
                enableDisableView(lnrOption1 as View, false)
                enableDisableView(lnrOption4 as View, false)
            }
            4 -> {
                if (data!!.right_answer == Const.SELECTED_ANS_D) {
                    lnrOption4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_round_option_shape)
                    txtOptionD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_green_circle)
                    txtOptionD.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                } else {
                    lnrOption4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_round_option_shape)
                    txtOptionD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_red_circle)
                    txtOptionD.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                    showRightAnswer(500)
                }
                ansText = data!!.optionFour
                enableDisableView(lnrOption2 as View, false)
                enableDisableView(lnrOption3 as View, false)
                enableDisableView(lnrOption1 as View, false)
            }
            else -> {
            }
        }
    }
    return ansText
}

fun showRightAnswer(duration: Long) {
    val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed({
        when (data!!.right_answer) {
            Const.SELECTED_ANS_A -> {
                lnrOption1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_round_option_shape)
                txtOptionA.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_green_circle)
                txtOptionA.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
            }
            Const.SELECTED_ANS_B -> {
                lnrOption2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_round_option_shape)
                txtOptionB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_green_circle)
                txtOptionB.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
            }
            Const.SELECTED_ANS_C -> {
                lnrOption3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_round_option_shape)
                txtOptionC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_green_circle)
                txtOptionC.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
            }
            Const.SELECTED_ANS_D -> {
                lnrOption4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_round_option_shape)
                txtOptionD.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_green_circle)
                txtOptionD.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
            }
        }
    }, duration)
}

private fun enableDisableView(view: View, enabled: Boolean) {
    view.isEnabled = enabled
    if (view is ViewGroup) {
        for (idx in 0 until view.childCount) {
            enableDisableView(view.getChildAt(idx), enabled)
        }
    }
   }
}
```

// Activity where loading fragment

```
  class OneToManyQuizActivityKT : BaseActivity(), 
  OneToManyQuizContentFragmentKT.OnAnswerSelected {
private val questions = ArrayList<OneToManyQuestionModelKT.Questions>()
private var pagerAdapter: TestViewPagerAdapter1? = null
private var currentQue: Int = 0
private var selectedAnsText: String? = ""
private var selectedAns = ""
private var selectedAnsPosition: Int = 0
private var rightAnsPosition: Int = 0
private var progressStatus = 0
private var isFirstTime = true
private var questionTimeCounter = Const.CHALLENGE_TIME_PER_QUESTION
private val timeForEachQuestion = Const.CHALLENGE_TIME_PER_QUESTION
private var isSkipped = false
private var oneToManyDotsAdapter: OneToManyDotsAdapterKT? = null
private var challengeId: String = ""
private var isOpponent: Boolean = false
private var initiatorId: Int = -1
private val handler = Handler()
private var challengeStatus = ""
private var wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock? = null
private var internetDialog: ProgressDialog? = null


private val updateRunnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        runOnUiThread {
            if (!Utility.isNetworkAvailable(this@OneToManyQuizActivityKT)) {
                if (internetDialog != null && !internetDialog?.isShowing!!)
                    internetDialog?.show()
            } else {
                if (internetDialog != null && internetDialog?.isShowing!!)
                    internetDialog?.dismiss()
            }
            questionTimeCounter -= 1
            if (selectedAns == "") {
                timeProgress.progress = ++progressStatus
            }
            if (progressStatus == timeForEachQuestion) {
                if (selectedAns.isEmpty()) {
                    if (oneToManyDotsAdapter != null) {
                        selectedAnsText = ""
                        questions[currentQue].question_status = Const.SKIPPED_ANSWER
                        oneToManyDotsAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        val fragment = pagerAdapter!!.getRegisteredFragment(test_viewpager.currentItem)
                        (fragment as OneToManyQuizContentFragmentKT).showRightAnswer(0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (questionTimeCounter == 0) {
            if (selectedAns.isEmpty()) {
                challengeQuizSaveAnswer()
                isSkipped = true
                val handler = Handler()
                handler.postDelayed({ nextQuestion() }, 2000)
            } else {
                nextQuestion()
            }
        } else
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
    }
}

override fun getLayoutResId(): Int {
    return R.layout.activity_one_to_many_quiz2
}

override fun initialization() {
    setScreenName(getString(R.string.ga_challenge_o2m_play))
    internetDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
    internetDialog?.setCancelable(false)
    internetDialog?.setMessage(resources.getString(R.string.waiting_internet))
    timeProgress.max = Const.CHALLENGE_TIME_PER_QUESTION
    recCircle.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    if (intent.hasExtra(Const.CHALLENGE_ID)) {
        challengeId = intent.getStringExtra(Const.CHALLENGE_ID)
    }
    if (intent.hasExtra(Const.IS_OPPONENT)) {
        isOpponent = intent.getBooleanExtra(Const.IS_OPPONENT, false)
    }
    initiatorId = if (intent.hasExtra(Const.INITIATOR_ID)) {
        intent.getIntExtra(Const.INITIATOR_ID, -1)
    } else {
        userId
    }
}

override fun initView() {
    test_viewpager.overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
    test_viewpager.offscreenPageLimit = 1
    test_viewpager.setPagingEnabled(false)
}

override fun setupData() {
    var powerManager = getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "ExampleApp:Wakelock Started")
    wakeLock?.acquire()
    if (intent.hasExtra(Const.CHALLENGE_STATUS)) {
        challengeStatus = intent.getStringExtra(Const.CHALLENGE_STATUS)
    }
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    manager.cancel(Const.CHANNEL_QUIZ_ACCEPTED)
    if (readPref(Const.IS_LOGIN) != Const.TRUE) {
        startActivityForResult(Intent(this, MainLoginActivity::class.java).putExtra(Const.INITIATOR_ID, initiatorId), REQUEST_CODE)
    } else {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        supportActionBar!!.title = Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#ffffff\">" + getString(R.string.offline) + "</font>")
        supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)))

        getChallengeQuestionList()
        val userdata = Gson().fromJson(readPref(Const.USERDATA), UserData::class.java)
        val userName = userdata.data.first_name
        txtStudentName.text = userName

    }

}

override fun setListeners() {
    test_viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {}
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            currentQue = position
        }

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
        }
    })
}

override fun onAnswerSelected(ans: Int, ansText: String) {
    if (questions[currentQue].question_status != "")
        return
    isSkipped = false
    selectedAnsText = ansText
    selectedAnsPosition = ans
    when (ans) {
        1 -> selectedAns = Const.SELECTED_ANS_A
        2 -> selectedAns = Const.SELECTED_ANS_B
        3 -> selectedAns = Const.SELECTED_ANS_C
        4 -> selectedAns = Const.SELECTED_ANS_D
    }
    when (questions[currentQue].right_answer) {
        Const.SELECTED_ANS_A -> rightAnsPosition = 1
        Const.SELECTED_ANS_B -> rightAnsPosition = 2
        Const.SELECTED_ANS_C -> rightAnsPosition = 3
        Const.SELECTED_ANS_D -> rightAnsPosition = 4
    }

    if (selectedAns == questions[currentQue].right_answer) {
        challengeQuizSaveAnswer()
        questions[currentQue].question_status = Const.RIGHT_ANSWER
        oneToManyDotsAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    } else {
        challengeQuizSaveAnswer()
        questions[currentQue].question_status = Const.WRONG_ANSWER
        oneToManyDotsAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    questionTimeCounter = 2
}


fun nextQuestion() {
    timeProgress.progress = 0
    selectedAns = ""
    selectedAnsText = ""
    selectedAnsPosition = 0
    isSkipped = true
    handler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable)
    questionTimeCounter = Const.CHALLENGE_TIME_PER_QUESTION
    if (questions.size > currentQue + 1) {
        progressStatus = 0
        test_viewpager.currentItem = currentQue + 1
        handler.post(updateRunnable)
    } else {
        if (wakeLock?.isHeld!!) {
            L.e("ExampleApp", "Wakelock Released")
            wakeLock?.release();
        }
        challengeFinishQuiz()
    }
}

private fun challengeFinishQuiz() {
    ChallengeMeDataProvider(this).challengeFinishQuiz(challengeId, initiatorId) { resultData ->
        if (resultData.code == 1) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, OneToManyThankYouActivity::class.java)
                    .putExtra(Const.CHALLENGE_STATUS, challengeStatus)
                    .putExtra("quiz_count", intent.getIntExtra("quiz_count", 0)))
            Log.d(TAG, "challengeFinishQuiz() Called Sussessfully")
        } else {
            if (!Utility.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
                showToast(R.string.no_internet_connection)
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "challengeFinishQuiz() Called field")
        }
    }
}

private fun challengeQuizSaveAnswer() {
    isFirstTime = currentQue == 0
    ChallengeMeDataProvider(this).challengeQuizSaveAnswer(isOpponent, challengeId, questions[currentQue].qid, initiatorId, progressStatus, isSkipped, selectedAnsText, selectedAnsPosition, rightAnsPosition, isFirstTime) { resultData ->
        if (resultData.code == 1) {
            val json = JSONObject(resultData.response)
            if (json.has(IS_SCORE_REVEALED)) {
                val isValid = json.getBoolean(IS_SCORE_REVEALED)
                if (isValid) {
                    showScoredRevealDialog()
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "challengeQuizSaveAnswer() Called Successfully")
        }
    }
}

private fun showScoredRevealDialog() {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.quiz_times_up))
    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok)) { dialog, which ->
        startActivity(Intent(this, OneToManyQuizResultActivity::class.java)
                .putExtra(Const.CHALLENGE_ID, challengeId))
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
    val alert = builder.create()
    alert.show()
}

private fun getChallengeQuestionList() {
    val dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", getString(com.topscorerstudent.app.R.string.loading))
    ChallengeMeDataProvider(this).getChallengeQuizQuestion(challengeId) { resultData ->
        dismissDialog(dialog)
        if (resultData.code == 1 && resultData.response != null) {
            val data = Gson().fromJson(resultData.response, OneToManyQuestionModelKT::class.java)
            data.data?.questions?.let {
                questions.addAll(it)
            }
            if (data.data?.questions?.isNotEmpty()!!) {
                pagerAdapter = TestViewPagerAdapter1(supportFragmentManager)
                test_viewpager.adapter = pagerAdapter
                handler.post(updateRunnable)
                oneToManyDotsAdapter = OneToManyDotsAdapterKT(questions)
                recCircle.adapter = oneToManyDotsAdapter
            }
        } else {
            if (!Utility.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
                lntInternet.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                group.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }
}

inner class TestViewPagerAdapter1 constructor(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    private val registeredFragments: SparseArray<Fragment> = SparseArray<Fragment>()
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return OneToManyQuizContentFragmentKT.newInstance(position, questions[position]).setListener(this@OneToManyQuizActivityKT)
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        val fragment = super.instantiateItem(container, position) as Fragment
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, `object`)
    }

    fun getRegisteredFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return questions.size
    }

}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        setupData()
    }
}

override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    return if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        true
    } else super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
     }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have to follow the flow I mentioned in the Question Part